# Phase Difference in Polarization of Dielectric by EM Wave

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, polarization

When we have an electric field interacting with a dielectric medium, the equation governing the macroscopic polarization is given by $\vec{P} = \alpha\vec{E}$.  This equation seems to also be used when the field is due to an EM wave, so the equation might look like $\vec{E}(z,t) = E_0\sin(kz-wt)$.  If we look at the example of a rectangular slab, it seems like if we inspect the displacement of electrons at different z values over a wavelength of the wave, we will have dipole moments that average to 0.  For example, at $z=\pi/(2k), t=0$ the electric field will have amplitude $E_0$ but at $z=\pi/k, t = 0$ the field will have amplitude $-E_0$, so the dipole moments at those two places will always cancel.  With this in mind, how do we arrive at a net dipole moment that isn't negligible for most solids, assuming that the only net dipole moment will result from some portion of the dielectric not being in a full period of the EM wave?

This question first occurred to me because someone mentioned to me that for EM waves incident on a plasma or certain solids, the scattered waves will all be in the same direction as the incident wave (or favor a certain direction) because of the phase interference for the free electrons (assuming the ions are fixed).  I am not sure why the same effect wouldn't occur in a dielectric, or if I am misunderstanding the effect for plasmas in general.  I would appreciate any clarifications or references to materials I can read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the EM frequency $\omega$ is low enough so that the dipoles can track it then the latter behave roughly if they were in a static field, such "low" frequency can be all the way to optical. I do not think for X-rays one can define permittivity meaningfully.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! To clarify if temporal frequency is low then wouldn't spatial frequency be high and we would get the cancellation I asked about due to the periodicity of the sin wave in space?

Comment: spatial frequency is always monotonically *increasing* with frequency, so if $\omega$ is *smaller* then $\lambda$ is *larger*.